# The volume "ok" could not be repaired

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

my macbook air 2011 just doesnt show the login window, after running fsck -yf it shows

```
...
Failed to issue COM RESET successfully after 3 attempts. Failing... disk0s2: no such device disk0s2: media is not present.
...
**** The volume "ok" could not be repaired
```

So what I could do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, the drive either has failed and needs to be replaced or needs a total erase, start from scratch, and load the files and OS from a backup copy.

You might be able to keep running on it, but it's like a bridge with cracks in it - it's best to collect your toys and get it repaired.

You could try a third party tool like Drive Genius or Disk Warrior, but most people don't need to spend $$ and can just do a backup / restore. I'd rather you spend $100 on a new backup drive than software that may or may not repair the issue.

On one hand - you have a backup drive that you can always use. On the other, you have traded $100 to roll the dice and see if software will fix the issue or if you still need to do the backup. You also want to budget for a potential repair, since many drives with this error are failing and need to be replaced. (*And you won't know that until you try to erase it and restore to put it back into service*).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response, luckily for me I have buyer this drive (256 6Gb from owc) so I have my old 64Gb drive and I replaced it. So I now have the 256 SSD plugged via USB... so I can erase it and see if works... but I have some "important" files inside it... is there a way that I can retrieve them?